# What globbing pattern will exclude a subdirectory except for two other subdirectories inside it?

Tags: jquery-ui, gulp, gruntjs, glob

I am copying over the jQueryUI library from bower.  I only want to copy over two themes from their "themes" directory.  The theme folders I want to keep are "base" and "ui-lightness".

How can I accomplish this with a globbing pattern?

I've tried this...

```
gulp.src([
    './bower_components/jqueryui/**',
    '!./bower_components/jqueryui/themes/**(!base/**)'
])
```

Here is the directory structure:

```
├── themes
│   ├── base
│   ├── black-tie
│   ├── blitzer
│   ├── cupertino
│   ├── dark-hive
│   ├── dot-luv
│   ├── eggplant
│   ├── excite-bike
│   ├── flick
│   ├── hot-sneaks
│   ├── humanity
│   ├── le-frog
│   ├── mint-choc
│   ├── overcast
│   ├── pepper-grinder
│   ├── redmond
│   ├── smoothness
│   ├── south-street
│   ├── start
│   ├── sunny
│   ├── swanky-purse
│   ├── trontastic
│   ├── ui-darkness
│   ├── ui-lightness
│   └── vader
└── ui
    ├── i18n
    └── minified
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Gulp v4.x**

The current gulp docs include an example [glob pattern](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#globs) which can be customized to meet your requirement. Try the following:

```js
gulp.task('copyfoobar', function() {
   gulp.src([
       'bower_components/jqueryui/**', // [1]
       '!bower_components/jqueryui/themes/**', // [2]
       'bower_components/jqueryui/themes/{base,ui-lightness}/**' // [3]
   ], { base: './' } )
   .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
});
```

The `Array` of globs shown above does the following:

- `[1]` Matches everything under the `bower_components/jqueryui/` directory.
- `[2]` Negates the `bower_components/jqueryui/themes` directory, (and everything in it), from the list created via the previous glob pattern.
- `[3]` Adds the `bower_components/jqueryui/themes/base` and `bower_components/jqueryui/themes/ui-lightness` directories, (and everything in them), back to the list.

***Note:*** The solution above assumes that the `bower_components` directory resides in the same directory as your `gulpfile.js`, and the target directory is `dist`.

***Resultant directory tree:***

If you don't want the `bower_components` directory added to your target/destination directory, (i.e. `dist`), then set the [base](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#optionsbase) option to:

```js
{ base: './bower_components/' }
```

This will result in something like this:

```
.
└── dist
    └── jqueryui
        ├── themes
        │   ├── base
        │   │   └── ...
        │   └── ui-lightness
        │       └── ...
        └── ...
```

Where as setting the `base` option to:

```js
{ base: './' }
```

results in something like this:

```
.
└── dist
    └── bower_components
        └── jqueryui
            ├── themes
            │   ├── base
            │   │   └── ...
            │   └── ui-lightness
            │       └── ...
            └── ...
```

---

**Gulp v3.x**

Unfortunately, the example shown above does not work in *Gulp version 3.x* because *Negations* (`!`) were handled differently - they were always done last regardless of the order they were specified in the glob `Array`. More info of that discussed in [issue 837](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/837).

The workaround, (for v.3.x), is to utilize [gulp-src-ordered-globs](https://github.com/UltCombo/gulp-src-ordered-globs) which will allow you to use the same `Array` of globs as the previous example.

The code for this will be:

```js
var gulpSrc = require('gulp-src-ordered-globs'); // require the gulp.src() wrapper.

gulp.task('copyfoobar', function() {
   gulpSrc([ // <-- gulpSrc() used instead of gulp.src() 
       'bower_components/jqueryui/**',
       '!bower_components/jqueryui/themes/**',
       'bower_components/jqueryui/themes/{base,ui-lightness}/**'
   ], { base: './' } )
   .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
});
```

Comment: Wow, great answer!  This is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
  gulp.task('copy_flolder',function(){
  gulp.src(['./bower_components/jqueryui/**', '!./bower_components/jqueryui/themes/**'])
    .pipe(gulp.dest('your dist folder'))
  });
  gulp.task('copy_only_Themes',['copy_flolder'], function() {
     gulp.src(['./bower_components/jqueryui/themes/base/**', './bower_components/jqueryui/themes/ui-lightness/**'])
    .pipe(gulp.dest('your dist folder'))
 });
```

Comment: I still want to copy everything under `'./bower_components/jqueryui/**'`.  But then in the `themes` folder I only want to copy those two themes.

Comment: so what you can do is create two task as in 1st task will copy everything in `./bower_components/jqueryui/**` expect `./bower_components/jqueryui/themes/**` and after that my above task will do.

Answer (score 0):

I just did this instead.  I think it was a little too difficult to figure it out in one task.

```
var task1 = gulp.src(base + 'jqueryui/*.*').pipe(gulp.dest(target));
var task2 = gulp.src(base + 'jqueryui/ui/**').pipe(gulp.dest(target + '/ui/'));
var task3 = gulp.src(base + 'jqueryui/themes/base/**').pipe(gulp.dest(target + '/themes/base/'));
var task4 = gulp.src(base + 'jqueryui/themes/ui-lightness/**').pipe(gulp.dest(target + '/themes/ui-lightness/'));

return [task1, task2, task3, task4];
```